# YOCTO (dunfell) and Mender on STM32MP157C-DK2

Tags: yocto, u-boot, mender

we’re trying to use yocto dunfell and mender on a STM32MP157C-DK2

Our ( probably bad ) idea is to replicate the STM32MP157C mender-community layer for yocto thud, creating the u-boot patches using devtool.

Now, we can build (obtaining the .mender and the .gptimg files) and start the board. The Mender server recognize the board as a pending device and it’s possible to accept it. But we have some problems with partitions.
If we use the mender client we get this error:

> Failed to read the current active partition: No match between boot and root partitions.: exit status 243

Moreover, if we use fw_printenv command we get:

> fw_printenv cannot read environment using default
> cannot read default environment from file

U-boot version is 2020.01

Any advice how to solve this issue?

Comment: You should post your question directly on https://hub.mender.io, they can help you with this specific question.